# How can i get a single image from a website using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape a store using HtmlAgilityPack, i got the product title, price, stock but i'm lacking the image. I searched how to get images using Agility Pack but all that i found is how to get all the images from the website, not just one.
I tried selecting the single node where the image is, doing something like this:
`var imgNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class = 'featured']");`
By doing this the imgNode value is equal to the whole img id html element, but i want to get only the current source from the src value.
The link from the store i'm trying to scrape is this: "https://www.fullh4rd.com.ar/prod/18381/monitor-27-gigabyte-g27fc-gaming-curvo-ips-165hz-hdmi-dp"
Thanks for your time ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `src` item in an html element, when seen as just an attribute, could be retrieved by it's attributes property.

However the above code selects a div, so once you select the child `img` element, you can access it's source:

```
var imgContainer = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class = 'featured']");

var imgNode = imgContainer.SelectSingleNode("//img");

var src = imgNode.Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Alternatively find the `img` directly using the id:

```
var imgContainer = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@id = 'mainpic']");
Console.WriteLine(imgContainer.Attributes["src"].Value);
```

Comment: I'm getting null out of that method. I also thaught about splitting the id, doing something like doing a node.innerText and splitting the id's to only get the src string, but the problem with that is that i can't get the img value with a string.

Comment: Edit made - I only saw that you were selecting a div now.

Comment: Your solution was the most accurate i found, but i don't know why src equals as a weird 1 px facebook pic, is there any way to try to search an img from it's id attribute? In this case  the id is called mainpic.

Comment: Another edit made - it would seem like you need to attach the base url to the output of that code.

Comment: That solved it, also to search from the image url i added the website's link, so for example with this link it was https://www.fullh4rd.com.ar//img/productos/Pics_Prod/monitor-27-gigabyte-g27fc-gaming-curvo-ips-165hz-hdmidp-0.jpg thank you very much for your time.